# How to add EF CLass Library to solution that will work with .net 4.5 and dotnet core

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, webforms, .net-core

I currently have a webforms website using .net 4.5.
I would like to add a class library with entity framewrok.
I want to make sure that this class library works with dotnet core and my existing webforms project.

With all the versions of .net, it is very confusing.
From what I gathered, dotnet standard maybe used as the middle ware for this type a situation. But I'm not sure this is true.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need .NET 4.6.1 or later

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll have to use the .NET Standard and Entity Framework Core. .NET Framework will be able to interface with the .NET Standard

I would start up with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECNLyvxLnuQ

There's not a lot of docs on standard, but this will give you some conceptual understanding

Answer (score 0):

Notice that "ASP.NET vs ASP.NET Core" and "Entity Framework vs Entity Framework Core" are completely different frameworks, even though which were named similarly.

ASP.NET and Entity Framework targets .NET Framework which means they can only work on .NET Framework.

ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core targets .NET Standard which means they can work on both .NET Framework and .NET Core.

WebForms bases on ASP.NET, and there is no (and not planned) migration for it on ASP.NET Core, so the old WebForms projects will never be able to work on .NET Core.
It is a great quantity of the task migrating from ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core MVC, and WebForms is even impossible.

If you really need to run your project on .NET Core, there will be a complete refactoring of your whole project:

1. Refactoring your WebForms project to ASP.NET Core MVC (Completely redevelop the whole project)
2. Refactoring your Entity Framework data definitions to Entity Framework Core (It only supports code-first and database-first, there is no model-first any more)
3. Make sure that all referenced .NET libraries target .NET Standard or .NET Core and reference them on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/). If not, re-target an alternative.
4. If your project is planned to be hosted on Linux server and referenced some native libraries, you have to get the equivalent .so libraries instead of .dll libraries.